# Does the Cassandra Java driver @Select annotation use Prepared Statements?

Tags: java, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Does Cassandra DataStax's @Select annotation use PreparedStatements in the generated queries? Is it effective like if I use a PreparedStatement and execute it manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, mappers also prepare the statements. If you observe the logs generated out of the mappers, you could see it prepare the statements for us. For e.g. when you [configure logging](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/core/logging/) you'll notice things like below when the mapper code is constructed,

```
DEBUG ProductDaoImpl__MapperGenerated - [s0] Initializing new instance for keyspace = ks_0 and table = null
DEBUG ProductHelper__MapperGenerated - [s0] Entity Product will be mapped to ks_0.product
DEBUG ProductDaoImpl__MapperGenerated - [s0] Preparing query
      `SELECT id,description,dimensions FROM ks_0.product WHERE id=:id`
      for method findById(java.util.UUID)
```

---

**Optional / Bonus**:
As recommended in the **DataStax Java Driver** documentation [here](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/manual/query_builder/#immutability), you could & should definitely leverage `PreparedStatement`s while working with `QueryBuilder` favoring bound statements for queries that are used often. You can still use the query builder and prepare the result:

```
  // During application initialization:
  Select selectUser = selectFrom("user").all().whereColumn("id").isEqualTo(bindMarker());
  // SELECT * FROM user WHERE id=?
  PreparedStatement preparedSelectUser = session.prepare(selectUser.build());

  // At runtime:
  session.execute(preparedSelectUser.bind(userId));
```